Python request get Invalid param error when using data from websocket result
token_info_list = []
list_lock = threading.Lock()

async def subscribe():
    global token_info_list
    async with websockets.connect(pump_new_pair_url) as ws:
        # Subscribing to token creation events
        payload = {
            "method": "subscribeNewToken"
        }
        await ws.send(json.dumps(payload))

        # Listening for messages
        async for message in ws:
            data = json.loads(message)
            if 'mint' in data:
                mint_address = data['mint']
                bonding_curve = data['bondingCurveKey']

                bonding_curve_percentage = await process_token_data(mint_address, bonding_curve)

                with list_lock:
                    token_info_list.append({
                        'timestamp': datetime.now().isoformat(),
                        'mint_address': mint_address,
                        'bonding_curve': bonding_curve,
                        'bonding_curve_percentage': bonding_curve_percentage
                    })


async def process_token_data(mint_address, bonding_curve):
    quick_node_url = 'my_quicknode_url'
    headers = {"accept": "application/json", "content-type": "application/json"}
    payload = {
        "id": 1,
        "jsonrpc": "2.0",
        "method": "getTokenAccountsByOwner",
        "params": [
            bonding_curve,
            {"mint": mint_address},
            {"encoding": "jsonParsed"}
        ]
    }
    print(f"Using mint_address key: {mint_address}")
    print(f"Using bonding curve key: {bonding_curve}")

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.post(quick_node_url, json=payload, headers=headers) as response:
            response_data = await response.json()
            print(response_data)

            # Extract the token amount and calculate the bonding curve percentage
            try:
                cur_amount = response_data["result"]["value"][0]["account"]["data"]["parsed"]["info"]["tokenAmount"][
                    "uiAmount"]
                bonding_curve_percentage = round(cur_amount / 1000000000 * 100, 2)
                return bonding_curve_percentage
            except (KeyError, IndexError, TypeError) as e:
                print(f"Error processing token data: {e}")
                return None

asyncio.run(subscribe())

I got Invalid param error when making request at "async with session.post(quick_node_url, json=payload, headers=headers) as response". The parameters mint_address, bonding_curve are from
Received message: {'signature': '2EstYg2KUUarp7rsHgDmJkNBUEwGHY4x9UVeMm2G5T9AXiguwksUwfCCWpmKiZgVRMRbLjy1yEV8npuSXcwXtEJ2', 'mint': '4i2PbHmbVJTht2E1z3psg7dHA49hRAZAqiDsKYVVpump', 'traderPublicKey': 'A6Aajy3dtRpaWvRqKpwBTfEzVxuBkeTQGNmoi4Ws5Pi', 'txType': 'create', 'initialBuy': 34612903.225806, 'bondingCurveKey': 'HhSUehdZf6RHyQHbDjEUp73dxb4NPr8FEX5UytZRfEtE', 'vTokensInBondingCurve': 1038387096.774194, 'vSolInBondingCurve': 30.999999999999986, 'marketCapSol': 29.853991922957412} 

which is from the websocket result in the first function. Error is:
Received message: {'signature': '2EstYg2KUUarp7rsHgDmJkNBUEwGHY4x9UVeMm2G5T9AXiguwksUwfCCWpmKiZgVRMRbLjy1yEV8npuSXcwXtEJ2', 'mint': '4i2PbHmbVJTht2E1z3psg7dHA49hRAZAqiDsKYVVpump', 'traderPublicKey': 'A6Aajy3dtRpaWvRqKpwBTfEzVxuBkeTQGNmoi4Ws5Pi', 'txType': 'create', 'initialBuy': 34612903.225806, 'bondingCurveKey': 'HhSUehdZf6RHyQHbDjEUp73dxb4NPr8FEX5UytZRfEtE', 'vTokensInBondingCurve': 1038387096.774194, 'vSolInBondingCurve': 30.999999999999986, 'marketCapSol': 29.853991922957412}
payload: {'id': 1, 'jsonrpc': '2.0', 'method': 'getTokenAccountsByOwner', 'params': ['HhSUehdZf6RHyQHbDjEUp73dxb4NPr8FEX5UytZRfEtE', {'mint': '4i2PbHmbVJTht2E1z3psg7dHA49hRAZAqiDsKYVVpump'}, {'encoding': 'jsonParsed'}]}
{'jsonrpc': '2.0', 'error': {'code': -32602, 'message': 'Invalid param: could not find mint'}, 'id': 1}
Error processing token data: 'result'

But when I take the result out and test it run successfully. like:
async def process_token_data():
    mint_address = 'uTPPrinDLf3GbUMZwfUvu2DBnvqwJiwaQNvUB1Zpump'
    bonding_curve = 'H1DViTNqGziSi6ewnsyDDfjpheVLB38kt78QVe2MgdCn'
    print(f"BC:{bonding_curve}, CA:{mint_address}")

    headers = {"accept": "application/json", "content-type": "application/json"}
    payload = {
        "id": 1,
        "jsonrpc": "2.0",
        "method": "getTokenAccountsByOwner",
        "params": [
            bonding_curve,
            {"mint": mint_address},
            {"encoding": "jsonParsed"},
        ],
    }

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.post(quick_node_url, json=payload, headers=headers) as response:
            response_data = await response.json()
            print(response_data)
            cur_amount = response_data["result"]["value"][0]["account"]["data"]["parsed"]["info"]["tokenAmount"][
                "uiAmount"]
            bonding_curve_percentage = round(cur_amount / 1000000000 * 100, 2)

            print(bonding_curve_percentage)

asyncio.run(process_token_data())

I got correct response,
{'jsonrpc': '2.0', 'result': {'context': {'apiVersion': '1.17.34', 'slot': 269614434}, 'value': [{'account': {'data': {'parsed': {'info': {'isNative': False, 'mint': 'uTPPrinDLf3GbUMZwfUvu2DBnvqwJiwaQNvUB1Zpump', 'owner': 'H1DViTNqGziSi6ewnsyDDfjpheVLB38kt78QVe2MgdCn', 'state': 'initialized', 'tokenAmount': {'amount': '999649529417483', 'decimals': 6, 'uiAmount': 999649529.417483, 'uiAmountString': '999649529.417483'}}, 'type': 'account'}, 'program': 'spl-token', 'space': 165}, 'executable': False, 'lamports': 2039280, 'owner': 'TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA', 'rentEpoch': 18446744073709551615, 'space': 165}, 'pubkey': 'G1k1Tm3vtjHUnbSpaM6FuBmyQuS171oiX7xM8P9JYo1t'}]}, 'id': 1}


I really don't know what is going on. It's driving me crazy. Please help.

Can you try deep.copy for data: data = json.loads(message) to make sure the value of data dont change when a new message come?
